# Namecoin: This transaction requires a transaction fee...But I have NMC

Tags: namecoin, rpc-error-4

When I am attempting to reserve a name using the command:

namecoind.exe name_new d/

I keep getting this error...
error: {"code":-4,"message":"Error: This transaction requires a transaction fee of at least 0.005 because of its amount, complexity, or use of recently received funds "}

However, I have more than .005 in my namecoin wallet, that I am attempting to register from. I have .01 in fact.

What is going on here?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with NMC, but my bet is that you have enough to reserve the name (the [.01](http://dot-bit.org/tools/domainCost.php) network fee) but then not enough to pay the transaction fee. If you wait a day or so for the coins to age, it might work.

Comment: @davidschwartz ah... that was totally it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have enough to reserve the name (the [.01](http://dot-bit.org/tools/domainCost.php) network fee) but then not enough to pay the transaction fee. If you wait a day or so for the coins to age, it might work.